# compiling for cross-platform use

Tags: compilation

I have a python script for a word game that uses a dictionary which is a unformatted text file.

I want to create an executable file and pass it on to my friends. They use Windows, Mac or Linux and none of them have Python installed. How can I generate an executable from my script so all my friends can run it and test the game?

Answer (score 0):

You can embedding the specific python binaries for each distribution in folders like python_win, python_mac, python_linux and create three distinct scripts launchers for each one passing on your application as parameter, this will work.